# how does a drill work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Naively when I want to make a hole, I put a bit in the drill and press downwards and a hole is produced.

Is it more complicated than that?  First of all every time I drill a hole in wood or any other material, shavings are produced, as well as a cylindrical empty space.  By conservation of matter, the shavings should have the same total volume as the volume of the hole I just made.

And there are other issues... how does a [screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw) (or screw-shaped bit) remove the matter?  how much heat am I producing due to friction? what is rotation speed etc.

The main question that motivated me to ask on here, is why a drill requires vertical force, but a router uses only horizontal force.  From theoretical point of view all both objects do is rotate a screw and remove matter from a piece of wood or metal.  So I need a better approximation of how these two machines work.

Comment: To make the initial hole with the router requires vertical force. Usually enough is provided by the weight of the thing. Then you're digging horizontally, so you need horizontal force after that. Think of it this way, if you didn't apply any force, the thing wouldn't go where you want it to!

Comment: @RyanThorngren Knowing zero about how tools really work, all I know is that I flip the switch and something rotates... As do many household appliances (washing machines, blenders, fans...) From the point of view of theoretical [mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), there's just a circle... How does that produce the effect I want?

Comment: Re, "a drill requires vertical force, but a router uses only horizontal force," Both tools move through the material in the same direction as the applied force.  You use a drill to bore a hole _in_ to the work piece.  You use a router to mill a slot _across the surface_ of the work piece.  Also note:  The cutting edge(s) of a drill bit are on its end.  Pushing in is what keeps the cutting edge(s) in contact with the material.  The cutting edge(s) of a router bit are on its side...

Comment: Re, "all both objects do is rotate a screw..." The screw on a drill bit is only there to help remove the shavings from the hole.  The part that actually _cuts_ the material (whether we're talking about a drill bit or a router bit) is a knife edge.

Comment: my impression of the tools is totally inaccurate. i think the typical person has no idea how tools work (the typical engineer or physicist may know a bit more).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know what is going on at the tip of the drill bit. Well, I would say that *scraping* or *gouging* or *digging*, but in a circular motion, would best describe it in layman's terms. It's similar to what happens when you scoop out ice cream with with a twisting motion. It usually requires at least a little force in the direction of the hole, but sometimes the bit sort of pulls itself in, depending on the material.

Note this: A drill requires not only vertical force, but torque, or twisting force as well. Often you don't notice it because it doesn't require much, unless it gets stuck, then you'll definitely notice it.

Screws are different. A normal screw does not remove material, rather it deforms material by pushing it out of the way. It squeezes and wedges its way in. That's why sometimes you want to drill a smaller hole first so that the screw doesn't have to squeeze in too tight and crack the material.

Edit: Ha! I just gave myself an idea for a better ice cream scooper for very cold hard ice cream, which has always frustrated me.

Comment: -1 This does not  explain the issues asked about in the question.

Comment: @sammygerbil ha, I'd say it does, given the level of understanding of the OP. The main (and only coherent) question is how a drill makes a hole. How do you think a drill makes a hole if my answer does not explain it?