# How Does a Drill Pierce Holes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

I know it's a very basic question, but I don't understand how a drill is able to make piercing a hole into an object easier. So, I could get a pin, and push it into the wall to create a hole, and that makes sense, but **how does a drill which is rotating perpendicular to the wall actually drill a hole?**

I understand we apply some downward force via a cutting edge on the drillbit, but does that imply that all the actual piercing is done ourselves and the drill just widens the hole and pushes out excess material that was pushed aside by the knife end? or maybe does it have something to do with friction deforming the material and pushing shavings aside?

Comment: The rotation might be required to remove material which comes in the path.

Comment: As noted, it isn't so much a 'pierce' as 'scrape/shave material off with a sharp edge over and over and over again until you have a hole'.

Comment: Related : [how does a drill work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396277)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drill does most of the work.

The drill rotates very fast, and so the cutting edges are also moving very fast.  When these sharp edges scrape across the metal, they are able to shear off some of the material that they are drilling through.  Here is a good side view of a generic machining tool cutting through a material in 2D:

[image: machining process side view]
(taken from the wikipedia page on [Machining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machining))

In this case, the cutting tool is the leading edge of the drill bit as it slides into the material, and the workpart is the material you are drilling into.  Cutting happens in a circular path to make a hole when drilling, but this diagram should give a good visual of what is happening at the point where material is removed.

The downwards force doesn't really contribute to the cutting motion.  All the downwards force does is ensure that the drill bit is constantly moving downwards so that the edge of the blade is below the new surface, which allows it to constantly drill downwards (unless the flutes get clogged or the drill overheats).

So really it's not even friction that does the cutting.  The drill bit is designed in such a way that when it's pushed down, the cutting edge makes contact with new material, and so it can continually remove material from the hole as you go deeper.  It's the very high rotational speed which makes this cutting edge move very fast, which is what provides the force that separates the material in the hole from the rest.

Comment: i may be being dense here, but i still don't really get what is happening. i still don't really get how it pierces into the material. if i slide my drill bit into the material and it spins to create a hole, doesn't that create another flat surface, then don't I have to do the work to slide it in further, like pushing a pin into the wood or whatever. sorry for not understanding.

Comment: @user2776326 You only really have to make a small indent by pushing and then the shape of the bit takes over pretty fast.  If you look up pictures of a drill bit, you should be able to see that if they get pushed in at all, they will start cutting mostly from the side instead of downwards.  It basically only has to push down a little bit all the time, and it can take a lot of the material away because of how fast it is spinning.  A majority of the material removal is due to the spinning component of the motion, not the downwards part.  Pushing down too hard can also overheat bits.

Comment: ah i see so it is kind of like whittling a bar of soap or peeling a carrot or something, and the point of the end of the drill bit is just to make a small indent. is that accurate, i guess that's what the relief angle is for, so the edge comes down at an angle as it spins. so it takes like thin horizontal slices all around kinda.